# Where should I buy travel insurance if I'm living in the UK on a work visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, insurance, schengen-visas

I currently live and work in the UK but I'm not a permanent resident. I'm scheduled to submit my documents for a (French) Schengen visa application in a few days and one of the requirements is travel insurance. However, it appears that local insurers here in the UK cannot cover me based on my residency status. How and where do I get my insurance? I have a trusted insurer back home but I can only give them my address in my home country. Can I only be covered by the insurer in my home country?

Comment: Searching for ‘travel insurance for non-uk residents’ might throw up something suitable? Eg I found https://www.expatriatehealthcare.com/travel-insurance-offer/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIg8n33NaP3QIVQ7HtCh3Ljw-dEAAYASAAEgKm9vD_BwE

Comment: There are plenty of *travel-specific* insurance companies that should be able to cover you for your trip. The fact that you're not a permanent resident in the UK should not matter, as long as you live/work in the UK. Local health insurance is not the same, and will not cover you. One that I have used (from the US, though, not the UK) is Allianz Travel. Check https://www.allianz-assistance.co.uk/

Answer (score -3):

https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-insurance/

Check if this works for you. If it does, it is really cheap.